# getting "#N/A" error when using importhtml formula

Tags: google-sheets

I was trying to import table from *morningstar* website to run some analysis of my own.

When I used `=importhtml(B3,"table")` where `B3` represents the link to the site, I am getting the "N/A" error.

http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US

The `importhtml` works fine with *gurufocus* site.

Can you help me out? I haven't been able to figure out what the issue could be.

from what i understand, *morningstar* doesn't use HTML or XML format for their table. If that is the case, is there a script I can use in Google Sheets that will let me extract data from *morningstar*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `importdata` to pull it in. try this:

```
=importdata("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&callback=?&t=AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc")
```

you can actually swap out the portion of the url that says &t=`AAPL`

for any other ticker symbol e.g. &t=`BAC`

`"http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&callback=?&t=BAC&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc"`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aurielle,
It worked for apple. now the trick is, how should i change the URL to make it work for each tricker. for example, now if i put in BAC, how should i change the URL? can you help me understand how did you create the URL. so i can manipulate it.
- Pratik

Comment: @pratik Sorry i also forgot to explain that i used the url i got from the download button. You should be able to swap out the ticker symbol etc for whatever you want if you want to change it

Comment: @pratik I edited the answer up top to answer the question more specifically - also the XNAS: part of the param that you see in the photo, i removed because its not necessary to function

Comment: wow!! you are a life saver :) it works perfectly fine. i have been trying to figure this out for over 6 months. i even posted this same question on multiple forums and reddit. but no one were able to find the answer! so glad i can finally start my analysis :)

Comment: Hi Aurielle, last year you had helped me import data from morningstar site by using the importdata function. I was trying to use the same practice for another site. "https://stockrow.com/api/companies/BSTC/financials.xlsx?d=y&s=income". 
 
but i was not able to get it to work. Can you tell me how was it that you got the morningstar link to work?
 
I am getting weird characters like the ones below.
 �wPK���������'�������

Comment: If you copy this app script and save it to your google apps scripts https://github.com/fastfedora/google-docs/blob/master/scripts/ImportJSON/Code.gs then use the function `=importjson("https://stockrow.com/api/companies/BSTC/financials.json?d=q&s=income")` that will do it

Comment: the reason its not working for you now - is because the filetype is xlsx on your stockrow source url

Comment: it doesnt work for me. I saved the code.gs file from your link into google apps scripts. and then used the importjson function in my google sheets. but it didn't work. I am getting "#Name?" error.

Comment: can you send me your email address on nobsjstcraiglist@gmail.com I hope you understand. i don't want to share the file here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no table in the HTML source of that page. It looks like this:

```
   <div id="keystuts">
        <div id="financeWrap">
        </div>
        <div id="keyStatWrap">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The empty div called "financeWrap" is then filled with data by one of many client-side scripts running on the page. Since the Google bot does not execute JavaScript on imported pages, it never sees the data. Unfortunately, this means it is impossible to import the data from that page using Sheets commands.